# Minicom status stays offline

Tags: 14.04, minicom

I have installed minicom through the following command:

```
sudo apt-get minicom
```

I am connected with the HP 5130 switch through a USB to Serial Console Cable. The name of my serial port is /dev/ttyUSB0 according to following command:

```
dmesg | grep tty
[    0.000000] console [tty0] enabled
[49689.082419] usb 3-2: pl2303 converter now attached to ttyUSB0
```

Extra check:

```
ls -l /dev/ttyUSB0
```

If I unplug the USB cable, I get following error:

```
ls: cannot access /dev/ttyUSB0: No such file or directory
```

So I assume its correct that ttyUSB0 is the right port

I edited the settings of minicom as following:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+   
| A -    Serial Device      : /dev/ttyUSB0                              |   
| B - Lockfile Location     : /var/lock                                 |   
| C -   Callin Program      :                                           |   
| D -  Callout Program      :                                           |   
| E -    Bps/Par/Bits       : 9600 8N1                                  |   
| F - Hardware Flow Control : Yes                                       |   
| G - Software Flow Control : No                                        |   
|                                                                       |   
|    Change which setting?                                              |   
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

and started minicom

However, I don't get any output except this:

```
Welcome to minicom 2.7

OPTIONS: I18n 
Compiled on Jan  1 2014, 17:13:22.
Port /dev/ttyUSB0, 15:02:26

Press CTRL-A Z for help on special keys

CTRL-A Z for help | 9600 8N1 | NOR | Minicom 2.7 | VT102 | Offline | ttyUSB0
```

I think the problem lies in the offline status?

Comment: did you solve it?

Answer (score 3):

See this part ...

F - Hardware Flow Control : Yes

Change it to "No" (or off ... whatever) and restart minicom.

Comment: that doesn't help

Comment: More info: https://wiki.emacinc.com/wiki/Getting_Started_With_Minicom Try also switch RX and TX.

Answer (score 0):

When you unplug and re-plug USB in the device is changed to `/dev/ttyUSB1` or `/dev/ttyUSB2` depends on how many time you re-plug the USB. Try connect with another device.

From error  `ls: cannot access /dev/ttyUSB0: No such file or directory` I believe that the terminal controller is changed to `/dev/ttyUSBX` when you re-plug the USB.

Answer (score 0):

Just `ls /dev/ttyUSB*` and then `sudo minicom -D /dev/ttyUSBx`

You can also use [my shell script](https://github.com/amitayben/test/blob/master/open_minicom.sh) that openw all of your minicom in new terminals:

```
#!/bin/bash  

open_minicom(){
PORT_IP=2
PORT_IP=$((PORT_IP+$1))
gnome-terminal -t "Minicom port $1 - 192.168.1.$PORT_IP" -x ./tmp_script"$1".sh
#./minicom_PORT.sh "$PORT_NUM"
}

generate_script(){
echo "$1"
PORT_NUM="$1"
PORT_IP=2
PORT_IP=$((PORT_IP+$1))
#gconftool-2 --set /apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Default/title --type=string "Minicom port $PORT_NUM"
#############################generat script
touch tmp_script"$1".sh
chmod 777 tmp_script"$1".sh
cat <<EOT >> tmp_script"$1".sh
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn sudo minicom -D /dev/ttyUSB$PORT_NUM -S set_ip"$PORT_IP".sh
expect {
-re ".*sword.*" {
    exp_send "$pass\r"
}
}
interact
EOT
###############################
#open terminal
}

generate_eth(){
PORT_IP=2
PORT_IP=$((PORT_IP+$1))
touch set_ip"$PORT_IP".sh
chmod 777 set_ip"$PORT_IP".sh
cat <<EOT >> set_ip"$PORT_IP".sh
#!/bin/bash
ifconfig eth0 192.168.1.$PORT_IP down up
EOT
}

MY_distractor(){
rm tmp_script*.sh set_ip*.sh
}


#printf "\n$NUM_OF_PORTS\n"
##############################
#             MAIN           #
##############################
NUM_OF_PORTS="$(ls /dev/ttyUSB* | grep -v ^l | wc -l)"
if [ $# -eq 0 ]
  then
    printf "No password arguments supplied\n Plase run ./your_script password \n Exiting......\n" && exit 1;
else
    pass="$1"
fi
if [ "$NUM_OF_PORTS" == "0" ]; then
    printf "Not found any minicom ports\n Exiting......\n" && exit 1;
fi
for (( i=0; i < $NUM_OF_PORTS ; i++ ))
do
    generate_script "$i"
done
echo "$(ls tmp_script*.sh)"
for (( i=0; i < $NUM_OF_PORTS ; i++ ))
do
    generate_eth "$i"
done

for (( i=0; i < $NUM_OF_PORTS ; i++ ))
do
    open_minicom "$i"
done
sleep 1

MY_distractor
```